# Name expected in an import annotation in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, compiler-errors, annotations

I have an Spring Boot App (2.1.6) implemented with Kotlin. Is a Rest api that wants to have oAuth 2 with Keycloak.
I have this code in Java that compiles ok:

```
package com.talleres.paco.mako.config.security;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "rest.security", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
@Import({SecurityProperties.class})
public class SecurityConfigurer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProperties;

  @Autowired
  private SecurityProperties securityProperties;

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId(resourceServerProperties.getResourceId());
  }


  @Override
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors()
        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        .and()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(securityProperties.getApiMatcher())
        .authenticated();

  }

  @Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    if (null != securityProperties.getCorsConfiguration()) {
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", securityProperties.getCorsConfiguration());
    }
    return source;
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenCustomizer jwtAccessTokenCustomizer(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    return new JwtAccessTokenCustomizer(mapper);
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(details);

    //Prepare by getting access token once
    oAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken();
    return oAuth2RestTemplate;
  }
}
```

When i convert to Kotlin i obtain a syntax error:

```
package com.talleres.paco.mako.config.security

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "rest.security", value = ["enabled"], havingValue = "true")
@Import({SecurityProperties.class})
class SecurityConfigurer : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Autowired
    private val resourceServerProperties: ResourceServerProperties? = null
    @Autowired
    private val securityProperties: SecurityProperties? = null

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(resources: ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer) {
        resources.resourceId(resourceServerProperties!!.resourceId)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(securityProperties!!.apiMatcher)
                .authenticated()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        if (securityProperties?.corsConfiguration != null) {
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", securityProperties.corsConfiguration);
        }
        return source
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtAccessTokenCustomizer(mapper: ObjectMapper): JwtAccessTokenCustomizer {
        return JwtAccessTokenCustomizer(mapper)
    }

    @Bean
    fun oauth2RestTemplate(details: OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails): OAuth2RestTemplate {
        val oAuth2RestTemplate = OAuth2RestTemplate(details)
        oAuth2RestTemplate.accessToken
        return oAuth2RestTemplate
    }
}
```

The error is in the line with the annotation import:

```
@Import({SecurityProperties.class})
```

I convert the code from Java to Kotlin with IntelliJ CE. The message is:

```
> Task :compileKotlin
e: D:\Workspaces\CleanArchitecture\mako\src\main\customized\kotlin\com\talleres\paco\mako\config\security\SecurityConfigurer.kt: (26, 34): Name expected
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess the tool that converts Java code to Kotlin is not always working. In this case `@Import` is defined in Java and it expects an array of classes, and you can use it in Kotlin by passing a `vararg KClass` (actually that works only for annotation's `value` field, otherwise you need to pass a proper array. More info [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#arrays-as-annotation-parameters)).

In other words, you need to change your code to: `@Import(SecurityProperties::class)`.

EDIT: it seems like this issue was reported and fixed years ago: [KT-10545](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10545). I also tried converting your Java code to Kotlin on my machine (using Kotlin 1.3.41) and the `@Import` statement was correctly generated.

Something funny, though, happened. The `@ConditionalOnProperty` line was converted to this:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "rest.security", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
```

which doesn't compile as "Assigning single elements to varargs in named form is forbidden". I'd be curious to see if it's a regression, as it looks correct in your snippet.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is fixed with your advice. But now I am thinking that if I delete the line i can fix the problem too. I don't see why we need import a class with annotation.